swig - calling char const * [] from python
I have C code with a standard main of the form
int mymain(int argc, const char *argv[]);

I managed to get through the swig 'pythonizing' process to be able to call this from python.  When I import my module and try to call mymain I get
>>>mymodule.mymain(1,[])
TypeError:in method 'mymain', argument 2 of type 'char const *[]'
>>>mymodule.mymain(1,["test"])
TypeError:in method 'mymain', argument 2 of type 'char const *[]'
>>>mymodule.mymain(1,"test")
TypeError:in method 'mymain', argument 2 of type 'char const *[]'
>>>mymodule.mymain(1,)
TypeError:mymain() missing 1 required position argument: 'argv'

and similarly changing argc to 0 or anything else didn't help.  Since the C is autogenerated I'd rather not modify that - can someone fill me in on how to pass a char *[] argument?  I don't actually care about the values being passed as main ignores them completely.

Try removing the const from mymain. For "real" main functions, they are at liberty to modify argv. Such as: strcpy(&argv[0],"x"); or char a[] = "y"; argv[0] = a;

Python's ctypes is a lot easier to use than swig.

Yes ctypes was the initial go-to but since another part of the project that autogenerates C can also autogenerate swig .i files we are trying to use it exclusively.  Another factor is that swig  supports multiple other langs besides python.

It looks like the swig 'typemap' allows one to take care of it: in the .i file you can add
%inline %{
int main_wrap()
    {
        const char* v[]={"foo"};
        mymain(1,v);
    }
%}

Reswigging this and recompiling, I can now call main_wrap() from python.

Needs "Foo",NULL to mimic main?

The code above works as written but possibly yours will work too, I don't currently have access to this machine.

Depends on how you loop through argv in your mymain function. For standard main, you can do (e.g.) for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv). But, compliant ones require a NULL entry at the end, so you can do: for (;  *argv != NULL;  ++argv)
